# My CSS and HTML files are not communicating properly to each other

Tags: html, css

Here is my code for my html file for a lockout database

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Locks Out Form</title>
<h1>Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form </h1>
<h3> *All fields must be populated </h3>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Lock Number</th>
<th>Equipment # or description:</th>
<th>Work Order #:</th>
<th>Date OUT::</th>
<th>Supervisor Inital OUT:</th>
<th>Comments/Tradesmen:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber" 
   required="required">
    </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber" 
  required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout" 
   required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout" 
    required="required">
  </td>
  </tbody>
  </table>      
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
  <br><br>
  </body>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin.php" target="_blank">Lock Check 
  In Form</a>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out 
  History</a>
  </html>
```

Here is my code for my css file

```
    {
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
h1 {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
color: white;
font-weight: 120;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
h3 {
color: #F81B1D

}

td,  th {
border: 2px solid #ddd;
padding: 14px;
}

 tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #214CD2;}


 th {
 padding-top: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 14px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: white;
}
body {
background-color: #4D4949;
}
a:link, a:visited {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}


a:hover, a:active {
background-color: red;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

The name of the html file is lockcheckoutbet.php and the name of the CSS file is lockproject.css when I go to add css formats to the links in the html file it is unresponsive and does not seem to work I can't find the problem of why the code is not working. If anyone could give me an idea of what is wrong with it that would be great! Thanks.

Comment: what are style head and body tags doing in the css file?

Comment: Please [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/). Your CSS doesn’t look valid, too.

Comment: its working properly..! you sure both file in same place,location

Comment: check your file path

Comment: Doesn't sound like you have a PHP problem here.

Comment: Sometime in browser the code is not updated. So you need to browse css file in browser and do refresh. Then You will refresh your html file in browser and it will be working fine.

Comment: </style>
</head>
<body> (These weren't supposed to be in the file I removed them)

Comment: Seems to be working ensure you put lockproject.css and html file in the same directory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working ensure you put `lockproject.css` and your html file in the same directory

```css
{
font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
border-collapse: collapse;
width: 100%;
}
h1 {
border-bottom: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
color: white;
font-weight: 120;
font-size: 36px;
line-height: 30px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
text-align: center;
width: 100%;
}
h3 {
color: #F81B1D

}

td,  th {
border: 2px solid #ddd;
padding: 14px;
}

 tr:nth-child(odd){background-color: #f2f2f2;}
 tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #214CD2;}


 th {
 padding-top: 14px;
 padding-bottom: 14px;
 text-align: left;
 background-color: #000000;
 color: white;
}
body {
background-color: #4D4949;
}
a:link, a:visited {
background-color: #f44336;
color: white;
padding: 14px 25px;
text-align: center;
text-decoration: none;
display: inline-block;
}


a:hover, a:active {
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<link href="lockproject.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<title>Locks Out Form</title>
<h1>Facilities Departmental Lock Checkout Entry Form </h1>
<h3> *All fields must be populated </h3>
</head>
<body>
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Lock Number</th>
<th>Equipment # or description:</th>
<th>Work Order #:</th>
<th>Date OUT::</th>
<th>Supervisor Inital OUT:</th>
<th>Comments/Tradesmen:</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<td>
    <input type="text" name="lock_number" id="locknumber"
   required="required">
    </td>
   <td>
    <input type="text" name="equipment_number" id="equipmentnumber"
  required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="work_order" id="workorder" required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="date" name="date_out" id="dateout" required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="supervisor_out" id="supervisorout"
   required="required">
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="comments_out" id="commentsout"
    required="required">
  </td>
  </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
  <br><br>
  </body>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/lockcheckin.php" target="_blank">Lock Check
  In Form</a>
  <a href="http://152.116.203.115/dataout.php" target="_blank">Lock Check Out
  History</a>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove

```
</style>
</head>
<body>
```

from the css file and make sure your css file is lying adjacent to your php file, if css file is inside a folder, then include a proper path like: /css/lockproject.css in the "" line.

Answer (score -1):

1. Please Check both PHP file and CSS files are in same directory.
2. Just remove these lines:

html:

```
     </style>
   </head>
 <body>
```

3. Change starting of CSS code from

CSS

```
{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}
```

To

```
*{
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
 }
```